# Finding second intervals in R time

Tags: r, epoch

I was going through some sample code in R that gets the last data for each second in a zoo object (time series). I get the code working, but i dont understand the following line:

```
time(tmp) <- as.integer(time(tmp) + 1e-7) + Epoch
```

Why do we add 1e-7 to the time value? Pasting the full code here. Kindly help

```
library(zoo)
zsec <- structure(1:10, index = structure(c(1234760403.968, 1234760403.969,
            1234760403.969, 1234760405.029, 1234760405.029, 1234760405.03,
            1234760405.03, 1234760405.072, 1234760405.073, 1234760405.073
            ), class = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"), tzone = ""), class = "zoo")

# tmp is zsec with time discretized into one second bins
tmp <- zsec
st <- start(tmp)
Epoch <- st - as.numeric(st)
time(tmp) <- as.integer(time(tmp) + 1e-7) + Epoch

# find index of last value in each one second interval
ix <- !duplicated(time(tmp), fromLast = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is a really good example of a place where you should have a comment in the code to explain things. "We added 1e-7 to the times to solve this weird bug."

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to do any thing. If I remove the + 1e-7 term, R tells me that I get the same structure

I think this is a rounding term, used to correct some sort of rounding error that might occur.

```
   library(zoo) 
   zsec <- structure(1:10, index = structure(c(1234760403.968, 1234760403.969,             
                                               1234760403.969, 1234760405.029, 1234760405.029, 1234760405.03,             
                                               1234760405.03, 1234760405.072, 1234760405.073, 1234760405.073             
                                              ), class = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"), tzone = ""), class = "zoo")  

   # tmp is zsec with time discretized into one second bins 
   tmp <- zsec 
   st <- start(tmp) 
   Epoch <- st - as.numeric(st) 
   time(tmp) <- as.integer(time(tmp) + 1e-7) + Epoch  

   # find index of last value in each one second interval 
   ix <- !duplicated(time(tmp), fromLast = TRUE) 
   time(tmp)[ix]

   tmp2 <- zsec 
   st <- start(tmp2) 
   Epoch <- st - as.numeric(st) 
   time(tmp2) <- as.integer(time(tmp2)) + Epoch 


   iy <- identical(time(tmp), time(tmp2))
```

iy <- identical(time(tmp), time(tmp2))

iy

[1] TRUE

identical((as.integer(time(tmp) + 9.99999e-1)), as.integer(time(tmp2)))

[1] TRUE

identical((as.integer(time(tmp) + 9.999999e-1)), as.integer(time(tmp2)))

[1] FALSE

Comment: Great . Even i thought so.. just seems to convert anything with > x.9991 into time x+1 seconds. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Wildly speculating but the most common reason for adding a tiny amount to something is to avoid divide by zero problems.  Perhaps the author wanted

```
time(tmp) - time(zsec)
```

to give non-zero ranges.  (Though note that `time` seems to be discarding the differences, since they are so small, which is why `identical(zsec, tmp)` returns TRUE.)